# start nodejs service from Tomcat

Tags: node.js, rest, tomcat

My goal is to deploy a war file to Tomcat and have Tomcat start my REST service.

Note that this is Tomcat app server, not Apache web server, so all the posts about mod_proxy and .htaccess will not work.  I understand that node does not need Tomcat, that node is not a servlet, that node includes an embedded web server, etc.  This is a customer mandating that the service be deployed to Tomcat via a war file.  Now I need to make it work.

Using "node myapp.js" from a command prompt, my rest service works fine on localhost:3000/terms.  Next, I stop the rest server running locally and build a war file using grunt and grunt-war.  The war file deploys to Tomcat without issues.  If I include a "hello world" as index.html then I can access that page at localhost:8080/myapp as expected.  However, when I attempt to access the rest service from localhost:8080/myapp/terms, I receive ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  I have also tried accessing the service at localhost:3000/terms after deploying the war to Tomcat.

I suspect that Tomcat is not starting the node rest service on deployment.

How might I 
 1. use Tomcat to either start the node service on startup like a
    servlet 
 2. run a command line at war file deployment so I can use
    "forever" 
 3. use a standard node module that I don't know about yet
 4. any other ideas the community may have

After three days of google searches I have ran out of word combinations and ideas. Thank you for any suggestions.

Wayne

Comment: So what's inside your WAR file? Just the javascript files for `myapps`?

Comment: Yes, it is a tiny test version until I figure out how to make the war file work. It is a single javascript file, 20 lines in size, using restify, mongoskin, and CORS.  On service that simply returns all rows in a single collection.  I stripped out express, angular etc to build the tiniest test case I could.

Comment: The web.xml is<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>myapp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: As you rightly pointed out, tomcat is a java servlet application container. It won't know what to do with a nodejs application (even if it is wrapped in a war file). Your customer's mandate is no different than trying to run .Net stuff on Tomcat (which of course, doesn't work).

Comment: My current thinking is to go down two paths - first, attempt to convince the customer that what we said above is correct and that we are trying to teach a pig to sing.  It just won't work.  At the same time, write the simplest possible servlet that will run a simple command line to start the node rest service as a background process.  I remain open to any other ideas.

Comment: Instead of using the servlet to start up `node`, you can use the servlet to redirect the user to your `node` app. So when your users navigate to http://localhost:8080/myapp, they get redirected to http://localhost:3000/terms. Otherwise, they get stuck at http://localhost:8080/myapp. What exact values are there in your customer's request to move the app to tomcat?

Comment: Educating the customer was the easier of the possible solutions.  Problem solved.

Comment: Maybe your customer needs something like a polygot paas such as [stackato](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYNRXlBfNmQ) to manage a multi-lingual development environment. Our customer finds it helpful.

Comment: Did you get this to run finally? I have the same requirement.

Comment: Somewhat. I was able to build the servlet, and the servlet can start the service as a background task. The servlet is configured to run on app server startup so that if the app server is running, so is the nodejs service. After getting the mechanics to work properly, and resolving the necessary permissions across three different login accounts, the client decided to use Java instead of javascript. This made the nodejs problem a non-issue.